# Asynchronous data pulling from a camera produces random crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a graphical application that is pulling data from a camera. The camera event loop runs in a thread that is started in a object, I use a setter / getter of the object to get the data out and use it. But sometimes the application crashes. I'm not using any synchronization mechanism.

I have this method:

```
void MyClass::onNewColorSample(ColorNode node, ColorNode::NewSampleReceivedData data)
{
    colorData = data;
}
```

I register it as callback of an external library:

```
g_cnode.newSampleReceivedEvent().connect(&onNewColorSample);
```

The method is called each time that a new frame arrives from a camera.

The getter of `colorData` is:

```
ColorNode::NewSampleReceivedData MyClass::getColorData()
{
    return colorData;
}
```

Then I use a pthread to run the following:

```
void* MyClass::runThread(void* na)
{
    g_context.run();
}
```

At some point I start the thread:

```
pthread_create(&pthread, NULL, runThread, NULL);
```

Then the class `MyClass` is getting data from a camera in a thread.

The run method documentation of the library says:

Runs the `DepthSense` event loop. The connected event handlers are run in the thread that called `run()`.

Now I use `myClass` to get data from the camera, in another class I have in a method that is called every 1/60 seconds:

```
static ColorNode::NewSampleReceivedData  colorFrame;
depthFrame = dsCam.getDetphData();
...
```

Sometimes the application crash in `dsCam.getDepthData()`.

I think that the problem occurs because the data is being copied when this method returns and in the middle of the copy operation I got new data.

I use a thread because the external library doesn't provide a non-blocking mechanism to get the data out. It just provides an event-based mechanism.

I'm afraid that if I use a mutex lock/unlock mechanism my FPS will drop down, but I will try it... please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem using QMutex:

```
//RAII class to unlock after method return (when local var out of scope)

class AutoMutex {
public:
    AutoMutex(QMutex* _mutex) {
        _mutex->lock();
        myMutex = _mutex;
    }
    ~AutoMutex() {
        myMutex->unlock();
    }
private:
    QMutex* myMutex;

};
```

then I just used this class, passing to it a pointer to mutex (mutex is a member of my class):

```
ColorNode::NewSampleReceivedData MyClass::getColorData()
{
    AutoMutex autoMut(&mutex); //mutex get locked
    return colorData;
} //when method ends, autoMut is destroyed and mutex get unlocked

DepthNode::NewSampleReceivedData MyClass::getDetphData()
{
    AutoMutex autoMut(&mutex);
    return depthData;
}
```